# Limit ForeignKey choices to ManyToMany field selections

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider this simple Django model:

```
class Apple(models.Model):
    oranges = models.ManyToManyField(Orange, related_name='apples')
    selected_orange = models.ForeignKey(Orange, related_name='apples_as_selected')
```

What's the right way to add a `limit_choices_to` to the `ForeignKey` field, such that it will limit choices only to those `Orange` objects that are selected in this instance?

I *would* want to do this:

```
selected_orange = models.ForeignKey(Orange, related_name='apples_as_selected',
    limit_choices_to: {'apples__id': lambda: self.id})
```

But I'm not sure how to get a reference to `self` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is on the `ModelForm` level, like so:

```
class AppleForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['selected_orange'].queryset = Orange.objects.filter(apples__id=self.instance.pk)

class AppleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AppleForm
```

Would still apreciate a solution to my original question if an elegant one exists.

Answer (score 1):

If this is specifically for use in the admin, you can customize the default form used when editing an existing object by overriding the `get_form` method:

```
class AppleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if obj:
            form.base_fields['selected_orange'].queryset = Orange.objects.filter(
                apples__id=obj.id
            )
        return form
```